# Multiple menu's in responsive hamburger menu

Tags: responsive-design, navigation, hamburger-menu

I am working on a website with drupal using bootstrap. I have different menu's on the desktop version: top bar menu, main navigation, sub navigation. They are in different locations.

When on mobile, I would like to show all those menus in 1 hamburger menu with collapsible links. What would be the best way to do that ?

I could create all the menus twice on the page, and then show/hide the menu depending on the viewport ... or is there a better way ?